# How do I activate jquery dialog boxes returned inside the tabs widget generated by an ajax datepicker event?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-ui-datepicker

There must be a simple solution that evades me. However I am very new to jquery so I am sure that is part of the issue.

I have a datepicker instance which submits a date via ajax and has xhtml returned via the tabs widget. I am trying to create dialog boxes in those returned tabs that explain what each of the different image products that may be returned, is. The there can be any number of tabs returned depending on the number of imaging events that happened on a particular day. And each or those tabs will have different images, but the explanation of the 'type' of image is the same. I have about 9 different image 'types' at the moment, but that may change at any moment so I should be flexible. For example, a sea surface temperature image will appear in almost every tab. A clorophyll image will only be returned in a day time event. There will be many images of the same 'type' within the different tabs (different pictures), but I only need to have one dialog explanation for each 'type'.

I currently use the jquery dialog boxes on the page, but since these are created onLoad() there is not issue with those ones. eg:

// Dialog Tip  
 $('#dialog_tip').dialog({
 autoOpen: false,
 width: 600,
 buttons: {
  "Ok": function() { 
   $(this).dialog("close"); 
   }, 
  }
 });

// Dialog Tip Link 
 $('#dialog_tip_link').click(function(){
  $('#dialog_tip').dialog('open');
   return false;
  });

I can control the output of the serverside ajax request as I write both ends. The actual original xhtml document is written serverside to start with. The **minDate** and **maxDate** are parsed when the serverside script is originally run to make sure valid data date range exists.

Here is the current contents of that event and it works fine.

$('#datepicker').datepicker({
  inline: true,
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  minDate: "**minDate**",
  maxDate: "**maxDate**",
  defaultDate: "**maxDate**",
  onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
         //alert(dateText);
         date=dateText;
         $.ajax({
          dataType: "html",
          type:"POST",
          url : "http://**HOST**/cgi-bin/image_data",
              data:"roi=**SITE**&date="+date,
          success : function(data) {
           $("#pagetabs").html(data);
           // find out how many tabs are present
               last_tab = $('#tabs li').length - 1;
           $('#tabs').tabs({ selected: last_tab });
               screenshotPreview(); // done so that I can make 
                                    // the js work for the larger 
                                    // thumbnails to pop up (works)
           // tab_dialogs(); expect that I have to call something here to
               // initialize the dialogs 
          }//sucess
             });//ajax
        } //inst
 });//datepicker

However, I cannot quite figure out how to get the dialogs created effectively, and to be hidden and then open. I know that I have to trigger it in the datepicker event. The issue is that I am not sure what to put into the above referenced tab_dialogs function. I cannot give all the images of a certain type the same id as that would break the DOM. And it seems that the dialog widget uses the id for the imput.

eg "$('#dialog_tip_link').click(function(){"

I can give them all the same class within each image type. I don't want to have to create 54 hidden dialogs for which there are really only 9 unique instances. So ideally, there would be a class for each of the image types. And hopefully, I can loop though the a.product_info (just a name) tags to get this to work. Obviously, I can't can't the existing javascript that the onload has since the ajax event doesn't change that.

Any thoughts greatly appreciated, mine are seemingly gone for the day/week?

PS, the next step will be to put the tabs into the Accordion widget so that the daily images appear first, and then the composited images are in a lower accordian style section.

Answer (score 0):

This kinda works for the tab_dialog except now I have several event handlers for each link so one has to think about using .one() somehow?

function tab_dialogs(){

$("div.product_info a").each(function(){
   var className = $(this).attr('class');{
   var $linkclassName = className + '_link';{
   var $divlinkclassName = "div." + className + '_link';{

```
$($divlinkclassName).dialog({
 autoOpen: false,
 width: 600,
 buttons: {
  "Ok": function() { 
  $(this).dialog("close"); 
  }, 
 }
});


$(this).click(function(){
 $($divlinkclassName).dialog('open');
 return false;
});
```

});
}

Comment: without any changes to the above, when I datepick another day, and then go back to the original date, I have to hit the close X or OK button several times to get it to close.

Comment: I thought I could $($divlinkclassName).dialog("destroy"); but no. I have datepicker a few other dates and changed the contents of the $divlinkclassName class, and the old one persists. That is the one I have to destroy somehow before I create the new ones. I can't remove() the dialog as that removes the newest one as well.

Comment: I added an separate class name called product_description to the dialog divs and then proceeded to remove them in the datepicker call prior to the return of the new product_description class divs.
      // get rid of old dialogs
      $(".product_description").remove();